# Grab and Swipe Cards

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slick.js

I'm creating animated cards with Slick, a JS Carrousel plugin.

I'm wondering if it's possible to add a grab and swipe interaction, as well as a pause on hover function, like the one shown here https://www.hioscar.com/individuals/network/ny

Here's what I've got so far: http://jsfiddle.net/gavinfriel/kbsemva0/1/

```
<section class="slider">
  <!--staff-card : The first card repeats unexpectedly-->
  <div class="staff-card">1</div>
  <!-- /staff-card -->

  <!--staff-card-->
  <div class="staff-card">2</div>
  <!-- /staff-card -->

  <!--staff-card-->
  <div class="staff-card">3</div>
  <!-- /staff-card -->
</section>
```

JS

```
$(function() {
  $('.slider').slick({
    speed: 07000,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 0,
    cssEase: 'linear',
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    variableWidth: true
  });
});
```

If there's a better plugin to use for this other than Slick I'm all ears.

Comment: cant you just remove `autoplay: true,` ? this [edit](http://jsfiddle.net/nrxys7y8/) seems like the solution you need

Comment: I think this is a native part of Slick, just set `draggable: true` in your options?

Comment: I used kineticJS for a similar effect before. It's available here: https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/

Comment: Cheers guys but it's all still a little buggy. If I use draggable and pull to the left, it jumps back into autoplay and and becomes undraggable again.

Comment: @ovokuro is there any demos of KineticJS floating around? Documentation seems a little light.

Comment: @GavinFriel I can't seem to find a working one, perhaps it was discontinued

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I'm not sure if this satisfies you, if not, then sorry :) Still I was trying to help ;) Well that's the best I could do :)

```
$(function() {
  $('.slider').slick({
    speed: 1000,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 0,
    pauseOnHover: true,
    cssEase: 'linear',
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    variableWidth: true,
    draggable: true,
    swipeToSlide: true,
  });
});
```

[Possible solution](http://jsfiddle.net/j080m3b1/)

Regards, KJ